# Heavy file transfert http

Tags: file, http, apache2

I'm working on a webapp in J2EE sending the content of files in http.
One file weight about 50mo and 10mo once compressed by apache. The browser asking for this file will try to retreive it until it crashes. I guess it's only due to the size of the file. I'm wondering what solution do I have to send this file (not often accessed)? Using a webapp with tomcat7 apache2. Like, is there a flush on apache or something like this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the browser was taking too much time indenting the content of the response so I added the header Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file in the response. This makes the browser download the content as a file instead of displaying it.